# Rails, Making a Rails form to save a record to an external db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

I haven't used Rails in awhile and I'm a bit out of practice.   For the application I'm working on there is an external db that's scanned by a running process and  creates tickets in a ticket system.   All I need to do is just save a record there.

I thought I could just connect the db and use a Rails form where I create a new model object and then a form uses that - where submitting the form should just go to a create action in the controller.

The error I'm getting from trying this has me stumped though (undefined method `tam_ticketings_path').

Thanks for any tips or help.   I never had to deal with saving a record to a db outside teh application and I'm not sure exactly what I should be trying to do here (save going back to an HTML form and a manual SQL Insert statment).

Thanks!

database.yml:

```
tam_ticketing_db:
  adapter: mysql
  database: tam_ticketing_1
```

model:  tam_ticketing

```
class TamTicketing < ActiveRecord::Base
  TamTicketing.establish_connection "tam_ticketing_db"
  set_table_name "tickets"
end
```

Tickets controller method:

```
  def new_ticket
    @ticket = TamTicketing.new
```

new_ticket view:

```
<% form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
```

the error:

```
Showing app/views/tickets/new_ticket.html.erb where line #1 raised: 

undefined method `tam_ticketings_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x3b01f18>

Extracted source (around line #1): 

1: <% form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>
2:   <%= f.error_messages %>
3: 
4:   <p>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `form_for(someModelInstance)` it will use the path method that goes to the create/update action.  Make sure you have properly routed your TamTicketing model using something like this in your `config/routes.rb` file

```
resources :tam_ticketings
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 2.3.5 the config/routes.rb should look like this:

`map.resource :tam_ticketing`

Then restart/start your server and browse your view again.

Also on your controller the proper naming for your action should just be 'new' and not 'new_tickets' inorder to have the above routing work correctly. Otherwise you need to add this:

`map.new_ticket 'tam_ticketings/new_ticket', :controller => 'tam_ticketings', :action => 'new_ticket'`
`map.resource :tam_ticketing`

I suggest making sure your controller is named TamTicketings (file name is tam_ticketings) and the action is 'new'

Comment: I'm still pretty confused, and I did map resources and connect the action and view I had.    There is nothing called "tam_ticketings".   The external db model is called "tam_ticketing", then the controller I had was called "tickets_controller".   Whatever is happening, Rails is trying to make a path out of the external "tam_thicking" db and adding an "s" to the end of it.  There's no controller or views for that model.   If anything it should be looking for an action in the tickets_controller called "new_ticket".   Sorry - I'm totally lost.  Thanks!

Comment: No idea why but if I change the form tag to specify the action it works: <% form_for(@ticket,:url=>{:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>